# Are homothetic additively separable preferences always equivalent to CES?

Tags: utility, preferences, production-function, ces-function, ces

Are homothetic additively separable preferences always a monotonic transformation of CES preferences?

In technical language, the question is the following:

Let $n>1$, and let $f:\mathbb{R}^n_{\ge 0}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$ be continuously differentiable, concave, and homogeneous of degree one. Here, homogeneity of degree one means that for all $s\in\mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$, and $x\in\mathbb{R}^n_{\ge 0}$, $f(sx)=sf(x)$.

And suppose that there exist continuously differentiable monotonic increasing functions $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$ and $h_1,\dots,h_n:\mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^n_{\ge 0}$:
$$f(x)=g(h_1(x_1)+\cdots+h_n(x_n)).$$

Must it be the case that there exists $a_1,\dots,a_n\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\rho,b_1,\dots,b_n\in\mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$ such that for all $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$, $h_i(x)=a_i+b_i \frac{x^{1-\rho}-1}{1-\rho}$? (Where, when $\rho=1$, we understand this as stating $h_i(x)=a_i+b_i\log(x)$.)

---

Note: This was first posted to math.se here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4648187/homogeneous-of-degree-one-functions-that-are-a-monotonic-transformation-of-an-ad but I think I have a higher chance of getting an answer here.

Answer (score 1):

The second to top "Related" question ([What utility functions are equivalent to additive functions?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/6908/what-utility-functions-are-equivalent-to-additive-functions?rq=1)) contained a link to Ted Bergstrom's [Lecture Notes on Separable Preferences](http://www.econ.ucsb.edu/%7Etedb/Courses/GraduateTheoryUCSB/separabilitynotes.pdf), which answered this question in the affirmative. The full proof is given in "Donald W. Katzner. Static Demand Theory. Macmillan, New York, 1970".